# Javascript how to get input

Tags: javascript, currency, converters

For school I need to make a currency converter.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Lab 10</title>
    <script src="lab10script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
    <select id="list">
        <option>dollar/euro</option>
        <option>euro/dollar</option>
        <option>ruble/euro</option>
        <option>euro/ruble</option>
    </select>
    <<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Exchange</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>


function myFunction() {
var bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag");
var x = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;
if (x == 0) { return (document.write("<br>test" + bedrag)); }
else { return (document.write("<br>test" + bedrag)); }
}
```

My problem is when I do a number like 8, it says "null", I'm learning JavaScript, so can anyone help me?

Comment: You don't have an element with id "bedrag". You've got an `<input>` whose *name* is "bedrag", but the name and id attributes are distinct.

Comment: Also `document.write()` is the wrong way to show results. A call to `document.write()` after the page has been loaded will completely overwrite the whole DOM.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` and `<meta>` tags do not use a closing slash and never have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

Change to this line and try again:

```
<input type="text" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

Change to this line and try again:

```
<input type="text" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

You can use console.log(bedrag) to see if the value is captured properly.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in the script,

```
var bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag").value;
```

instead of,

```
var bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag");
```

and add `id="bedrag"` in `input`, because you are accessing an element by id

```js
function myFunction() {
  var bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;
  if (x == 0) { return (document.write("<br>test" + bedrag)); }
  else { return (document.write("<br>test" + bedrag)); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="nl">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Lab 10</title>
    <script src="lab10script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="bedrag" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
    <select id="list">
        <option>dollar/euro</option>
        <option>euro/dollar</option>
        <option>ruble/euro</option>
        <option>euro/ruble</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Exchange</button>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the name attribute on the input with id as in

```
<input type="text" name="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

Should become

```
<input type="text" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
```

I am not sure but from the question and code it seems you are only trying to display the value entered. In that case try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Lab 10</title>
        <script src="lab10script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form">
            <input type="text" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in" />
            <select id="list">
                <option>dollar/euro</option>
                <option>euro/dollar</option>
                <option>ruble/euro</option>
                <option>euro/ruble</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Exchange</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag").value;
                var x = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;
                if (x == 0) { 
                    //log the value to console and verify the value
                    console.log("<br>test" + bedrag); 
                }
                else { 
                    console.log("<br>test" + bedrag); 
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```